# How to check resync of megaraid?

Tags: raid

I previously use software-based raid, and 'cat /proc/mdstat' can show the resync progress. Now I use hardware-based raid (perc h710p), I wonder if there is way to check resync progress using MegaCli. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer yet, this should work:

```
MegaCli64 -LDRecon ShowProg L0 -a0
```

This website has a lot of useful MegaCLI commands: http://artipc10.vub.ac.be/wordpress/2011/09/12/megacli-useful-commands/